# refreshing the local server ip not refreshing the newly enabled site

Tags: php, apache2

I have changed the DocumentRoot from `/var/www/pydio/pydio-core-6.2.2` to `/var/www/php/cloud` and updated the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/cloud.conf` as below

php directory contains cloud directory which was earlier pydio and it was working.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin pydio@localhost.localdomain.com
      ServerName 192.168.1.2
      DocumentRoot /var/www/php
      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/pydio-error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/pydio-access.log combined
      <Directory /var/www/php/>
      AllowOverride All
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

after doing the above change I ran `sudo a2ensite cloud` which worked fine, but when I reload apache `sudo service apache2 reload` which also works fine but then if I try to reload the page of using the same IP it still points to old website 000-default which I enabled and reload apache2 before doing the above renaming.

It has been more than 1 hour now it should have refreshed by now.

here is the tree of directory structure

```
$ pwd
/var/www
$ tree -L 3
.
|-- html
|   `-- index.html
`-- php
    |-- cloud
    |   |-- base.conf.php
    |   |-- cmd.php
    |   |-- conf
    |   |-- content.php
    |   |-- core
    |   |-- data
    |   |-- dav.php
    |   |-- index.php
    |   |-- index_shared.php
    |   |-- phpunit
    |   |-- plugins
    |   |-- publicLet.inc.php
    |   |-- rest.php
    |   `-- runTests.php
    |-- index.php
    `-- install_website_here
```

please bear with me, and apologies if I am doing it the crude way , I am not a web developer this is the first time I am setting this up, earlier I followed some tutorial but now I am learning by troubleshooting and digging.

Comment: This may sound crazy... try rebooting the server and see what happens. Sometimes that works.

Comment: I did that already when I faced this issue

Comment: Okay. Sometimes it is like Apache gets stuck and ignores setting changes during a restart and a reboot makes it all work again.

Comment: You state that you've "changed the DocumentRoot from `/var/www/pydio` to `/var/www/cloud`", yet it shows `DocumentRoot /var/www/php` in your VirtualHost?

Comment: @w3dk sorry that was typo in my post, I have fixed it. Thanks

Comment: today i started the server and it seems to be working

Comment: I'm closing this because you indicate that you found the problem and it was due to a typo.    Soliciting further answers to this question are unlikely to help other users.

Comment: please go ahead (y)